# How do I set maximum number of simultaneous downloads on Transmission server

Tags: kodi, server, media-server

I have a transmission server set up as an addon for LibreELEC, which is installed on my Raspberry Pi 3. I downloaded it from this [repo](https://github.com/thoradia/thoradia/tree/master/8.2/RPi2/arm) by a member on the LibreELEC forums.

I can access this server on the local network from the browser using an IP address like so: `192.168.0.xx:9091/transmission/web`

I usually don't want more than one torrent to be downloading at a time. But there doesn't seem to any way from the GUI to set the maximum number of simultaneous downloads. I also tried the `Configure` option for the addon within the LibreELEC GUI but there was no option there either.

Is there any other way to set the max number of simultaneous downloads, perhaps by modifying a settings file?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any relevance for Raspberry Pi - the forum here. If it does have some relevance to Raspberry Pi, please edit your question to show the connection. If not, you may wish to look at some of the other StackExchange forums; [super user](https://superuser.com/) would be a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to change the `download-queue-size` variable to `1` in `settings.json`, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Editing-Configuration-Files).

However it isn't immediately clear from the documentation where to find this file when Transmission is installed as an addon on LibreELEC or some other version of Kodi. It is in the following location:

`~/.kodi/userdata/addon_data/service.transmission/settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the config file, changing `download-queue-enabled` to `True` and `download-queue-size` to whatever size you like. Here's [documentation for your reference](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Editing-Configuration-Files).